# Vue подставить готовое значение вместо null

Tags: vue.js

Пытаюсь подставить заранее полученное значение "pk" в "originPublicKey",
Проблема в том, что в условии this.originPublicKey всегда равен null. 
Если я подставлю originPublicKey: pk, то скрипт перестает работать, подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
    const pk = localStorage["public_key"]

    const vm = new Vue ({   
      el: '#vue-instance',
      data () {
        return {
          cryptWorker: null,
          socket: null,
          originPublicKey: null,
          destinationPublicKey: null,
          messages: [],
          notifications: [],
          currentRoom: null,
          pendingRoom: localStorage["default_room"],
          draft: ''
        }
      },
async created () {
    this.cryptWorker = new Worker('crypto-worker.js')
    if(pk === null || this.originPublicKey == null){
        this.addNotification(lang['createPublicKey']) 
        $("#reload_status").html(lang['createConnection'])
        this.originPublicKey = await this.getWebWorkerResponse('generate-keys')
    }

    this.socket = io()
    this.setupSocketListeners()
  }
```

Comment: Пробовал делать так, все равно ругается (  `async created () {
    this.cryptWorker = new Worker('crypto-worker.js')
    if(pubKey == null || this.originPublicKey == null){
  pubKey = await this.getWebWorkerResponse('generate-keys')
  this.originPublicKey = pubKey 
 }  
    this.socket = io()
    this.setupSocketListeners()
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```js
created() {
  this.originPublicKey = pk
}
```

Comment: при проверке код не работает, сообщения не доходят, crypto-worker.js ругается